# ASP.NET 5 - How to plug custom SessionIdManager to StateServer session mode

Tags: asp.net, .net

In previous ASP.NET versions ASP.NET session state supports several different storage options for session data. We can specify the mode we want by setting the **mode** attribute of the sessionState element in web.config. **In ASP.NET 5**, how can we set the mode for **StateServer** for session storage and where can we add a custom **[SessionIDManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)** implementation?